Stream data not showing up in DebugView
I'm fairly new to google analytics but I'm working on a tracking pixel that we include in our emails to see which users opened / read our newsletter.
We have to use this approach because the software we have to use doesn't support any plug ins to natively include google analytics.
I have set up an analytics account including a new web stream and I'm trying to run a test request using curl.
curl -v "https://www.google-analytics.com/g/collect?v=2&tid=Gxxxxxx&cid=123.123&en=email_open&debug_mode=1"

However when I execute this request I don't receive any data in google analytics.
I receive a 204 return code which should be fine so I have to be doing something wrong.
FYI: I already checked the filter configuration etc. for my stream and I think I should be good there.
When my test request is showing up in analytics we plan to include an html image snippet in our emails to implement the tracking.
Thanks a lot in advance
